# Unable to run Call Execute within a Data Step

Tags: sql, sas

I am trying to run an insert statement within a data step to populate a table. I get the following error while running the code ERROR: Domain error. There is no other information on this error i the logs.

The sample code which I am implementing is :

```
  DATA _NULL_;
  SET DataSetA;

 Call Execute ('Proc Sql; Insert Into TableA Select col1,col2,c.Col2 From Table B Inner        Join ( Select col1,' || Datasetcol1 || ' As col2, ' || Datasetcol2 || ' as Col3 FROM ' || Datasetcol3 || ' ) c On b.Col1=c.col1;quit;');

 run;
```

This code runs okay if there are 2000 records but now I have 10000 records and throws me that error. Datasetcol1 and Datasetcol2 are values from the dataset which I am using in the query.

I have no idea why this error occurs. Initially, I thought it could be because of the processor having too much work, I put in a wait by using sleep and wakeup , however, I still get the error. Also, I dont get this error always. It happens sometimes and sometimes it doesnt.

Comment: Are TableA and TableB in your work folder?  Or are they in a libname?  If they are in a libname, is it a SAS library or an ODBC library?

Comment: They are in a libname and its a SAS library

Answer (score 2):

I am in the middle of running Joe's code and I am having no issues.  This is on Windows 7 with SAS 9.2m3, so that may be different environment than yours.  Also since I do not have you data, I can not replicate what you have done.

I see lots of things which might improve the code, but the error message indicates some problem deep within SAS.  I generally find it more efficient to check with SAS Tech support rather than speculate about what may be happening in the Black Box called SAS.  Submit a ticket on this.

I did fine one reference to this error message on  the SAS support site which points to Oracle specific issue. http://support.sas.com/kb/14/873.html

Comment: Looking at your comments, I think I agree with Larry that this is a data integrity problem most likely (though I still recommend at least pursuing my solution, if not a better method using bulk insert).  Probably you have one (or more) rows with some invalid data that cannot appear in a field (like the linked Oracle column that cannot have 0000-00-00 in date), and it only appears when you get to a certain point in your data.

Comment: I have not yet tried out Joe's logic, will do it in sometime. I am on SQL server and am trying to insert values into SAS tables itself. Also, with regard to data, if i have 10000 records the final insert table consists of 10001 records with one record being duplicated. The record which gets duplicated varies on every run.

Answer (score 1):

First, I'd try removing the 'PROC SQL;' and 'QUIT;' from your repeated CALL EXECUTE, and run them only once each - using IF *N* = 1; to run the PROC SQL, and you can either use a LAST variable to determine when to call the QUIT, or just leave it out of the datastep and write QUIT; after the RUN; of the data step, as that would then execute in the proper place.  It is possible the repeated invocation of the SQL environment is causing your problem itself.

Another possible solution would be instead of using CALL EXECUTE, write these all to a text file, then %include that text file.  Again, %include the part not including PROC SQL and QUIT, and %include inside a PROC SQL block.  If CALL EXECUTE is specifically at fault here, this gets around that with no difference in function.  Honestly I'd prefer this method anyway, as it's a) closer to what you're really doing (writing SQL code programatically, then executing it), and b) easier to debug (it writes a text file you could then grab lines from to test).

Edit: Example of removing the PROC SQL and QUIT from the calls:

```
data class;
set sashelp.class;
run;

filename _null dummy;
proc printto log=_null;
data _null_;
set sashelp.class end=eof;
if _n_ = 1 then call execute('PROC SQL;');
do _t = 1 to 10000;
  _exec = cats('insert into class (name,age,sex) select name,age,sex from sashelp.class where name="',name,'";');
  call execute(_exec);
end;

if eof then call execute('QUIT;');
run;
```

Comment: I created a text file and then did the %include. However, your way of not putting proc sql and quit inside the text file but enclosing the entire file in a proc sql quit, does not work.

Comment: I am trying to remove the proc sql and quit from my execute statement but either the system hangs if i place quit after run or nothing happens. Any example would help greatly.

Comment: Hey Joe, Thank you for the sample code, but my system just hangs on executing it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're right that the cause is due to scaling issues with `call execute`.  The limit could be determined by a variety of things such as the amount of available memory, limits to the instruction queue (I made that up btw), etc...

A good practice in this case would probably be to process the call executes in batches of 1000 using the `firstobs` and `obs` options on your dataset set statement.

```
DATA _NULL_;
  SET DataSetA(firstobs=1 obs=1000);
  *Call Execute ...;
run;

DATA _NULL_;
  SET DataSetA(firstobs=1001 obs=2000);
  *Call Execute ...;
run;
```

And then macro-ise the above code as necessary...

Comment: I split it into 10 data sets and ran a macro to do the thing, still get that error.

Answer (score 0):

For such huge code generation a safer approach is to generate an external file and run it:

```
 DATA _NULL_;
  SET DataSetA;
  file "script.sas";
  length stmt $200;
  stmt = 'Proc Sql; Insert Into TableA Select col1,col2,col3 From Table B Inner        Join ( Select col1,' || Datasetcol1 || ' As col2, ' || Datasetcol2 || ' as Col3 FROM Table C) c On b.Col1=c.col1;quit;';
  put stmt;
 run;

 %include "script.sas" ;
```

This also gives you a place to check the generated code while working on your code.

Note: take care of the length for the variable that holds the code (`stmt $200` here) and linesize of the external file (256 by default).

Comment: I generated the external file and I can see the code under the file. The only thing is that the file is getting created under a different folder. so when I do %Include "script.sas" I get the error that the physical file does not exist. Is there anyway I could specify the location for the file to be generated?

I have recently started coding in SAS and do apologize if the questions sound too naive.

Comment: Just specify a complete path to a local file in both the `file` statement and the `%include` statement.

Comment: Thanks @BobDuell for that pointer. 

However, this method too failed. I still get the error: Domain error. I guess successive proc sql calls dont work on SAS. Or am I missing something?

Comment: What version of SAS are you using and on what operating system?  I'm guessing that your generated program is too large.  From what I see, you are trying to run PROC SQL 10,000 times and that "Domain error" is probably related to memory or some other resource.  I would very much try to come up with a different solution to your problem.

Comment: I am running the enterprise guide for SAS 9.1 on unix operating system

Comment: Is it a specific SQL statement that's failing?  Perhaps there's a funny character in the data being used to build the SQL statements?  When you use this method and %include the file a second time, will at fail at exactly the same line as it did the first time?  If so, try running just that line of SQL by itself.

Comment: Its the same SQL which is being called over and over, where it fails for one record. However, it carries on inserting for the next records.  It gives me that error but inserts that record for which the error occured, and in the next step runs it again for that same record inserting it again. It fails at different records for each run.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to avoid the use of `call execute` completely by doing everything through the macro facility.

Example:

```
%macro InsertFromTable(table_name, ds_col1, ds_col2);
    proc sql;
        Insert Into TableA 
        Select col1,col2,col3 
        From Table B 
        Inner Join ( 
            Select col1
                ,&ds_col1. As col2
                ,&ds_col2. as Col3 
            FROM &table_name. as C
        ) c On b.Col1=c.col1
    ;quit;
%mend;


%Macro InsertFromAllTables();
    %let dsid=%sysfunc(open(DataSetA,i));
    %syscall set(dsid);

    %let rc = %sysfunc(fetch(&dsid));
       %do %while (&rc. eq 0);            
            %InsertFromTable(&table_name., &col1., &col2.);
            %let rc = %sysfunc(fetch(&dsid));            
       %end;
    %let rc=%sysfunc(close(&dsid));
%mend;


data DatasetA;
    infile datalines firstobs=3 missover;    
    input table_name: $10. col1: $10. col2: $10.;

    datalines;    
    table_name   col1   col2
    ----------   ----   ----
    Table_1       C1      C2
    Table_2       D1      D2
    Table_x       xx      yy
;run;



%InsertFromAllTables();
```

Comment: I did this got the same error, I think its the repeated proc sql calls which is causing the problem.

Comment: I don't think it's repeated proc sql calls that are the issue... SAS should be able to sit there and call proc sql all day without a problem.  There's something more to it...

Comment: @stevepastelan I like how you add table headers to your datalines statement and specify firstobs=3... I'm totally stealing that.

Comment: @Rob I am releasing the technique into the public domain :)

Comment: @Som Have you looked into your SAS/database/environment configuration? Possibly you have some restriction that simply doesn't allow you to make so many queries in rapid succession?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to split this off into another answer since it's entirely different from my original thoughts.

I would assume first that this is a data error.  Troubleshoot by doing the following:
1.  Use the first 5000 rows.  If that succeeds, then use only the second 5000 rows (firstobs=5001).  If neither fails, then it is not a data error; if one or both fail, it might be a data error.
2.  Then perform a binary tree search-like algorithm.  Say the first 5000 fails.  Then try the first 2500.  If that fails then try the first 1250.  Continue until you find something that passes.  Then try the other half of the last one that passed (say, 625 passed; so try 626-1250).

Continue splitting in half until you have a small set of data you can inspect (one row, five rows, whatever is best for your ability to see the data, particularly based on how many rows the inner join creates).  Look at the rows and see if anything pops out as possibly illegal.

Of course if you get to a particular size (say 625) and find that all sets of 625 from 1 to 10000 pass, just not when combined into larger sets, you again may not have a data error - but I'd think it's likely you do, particularly given the link Larry posted.

If you want a somewhat faster solution, consider doing frequencies of the relevant variables in both DatasetA and TableA/B.  See if anything in one of those rows is perhaps illegal, or unusual.  If you see a date that's impossible, for example, or a negative number that doesn't make sense, perhaps it's at fault.

Finally, what system is this inserting rows into?  I hope not SAS (as there are many better SAS-sy solutions).  Depending on the system, you may be violating one of that system's rules (like in Larry's link) or you may be violating table constraints or something else that SAS doesn't have a special error message for, but nonetheless does break some rule.  The phrase Domain Error could be construed that way, in any event.

Comment: Well just to give an update, when I change from firstobs=1 to firstobs=1000 it still reads from the first observation itself. Secondly I ran it from 1 to 1000, 1 to 1500, 1 to 2000, 1 to 2500 where it failed at the 700th record.

Comment: Do you mean record as in the SAS dataset's record, or the SQL table you're inserting into?  FIRSTOBS will control which SAS dataset record (the dataset driving the CALL EXECUTE) you read in, but not the SQL table.  That will always be the same unless you filter that somehow.  ** Did it fail at the 700th record each time?  Or only in the 1-2500 run?

Comment: I am inserting into the SAS table. Weh I ran it all together from 1 -2500 it failed twice once at 700 and the other at 1130. It never failed when I ran from 1-500;1-1000;1-1500;1-2000.

Comment: If you're doing this entirely in SAS then why are you doing it this way?  It looks like you're just adjusting table C to have columns 2 and 3 be various different column pairs from table A - so instead of constructing this on the fly, make a permanent table C with the appropriate 3 columns.  Then you could do a bulk insert which would be much much faster.

Comment: I did not pay attention to the code before, I actually was using some other statement and had not updated it. My dataset consists values of column name and table name which I am utilizing to get some values. I am not sure if it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the most recent version of SAS (version 9.3 Maint 2), you might try the DOSUBL statement.  It allows you to run any collection of SAS statements from within a DATA step, as long as those statements represent a "complete" step. That is: global statements, DATA step with RUN;, PROC step with RUN/QUIT.

It's marked as Experimental, but basic documentation and examples are available in [this SAS Global Forum 2012 paper](http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings12/227-2012.pdf).

Note: even though DOSUBL was valid syntax in SAS 9.3 initially, my experience is that it works much better with SAS 9.3M2.