# Can this run in a Macro?

Tags: sql, sas

I have been trying to resolve an  [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12924653/unable-to-run-call-execute-within-a-data-step)  and using a different approach to resolve it. I have created a macro to get actual value. The sql generates an HTML view with the values I need.

```
 %macro actualvalue();

 proc sql noprint;

 %do i=1 %to %wordcount(&fieldlist);

 Select %scan(&fieldlist,&i) into :actualvar separated by ' ' FROM TableA Where        
 IncidentItemId=%scan(&incidentitemlist,&i);

 %end;

 quit;

 %mend actualvalue;
```

However, the actualvar macro variable does not seem to capture the value. Is there something wrong in the way I am trying to initialize the macro variable or this cannot be performed inside a macro. Any thoughts on this would be appreciated.

Comment: To solve a macro construction problem try inserting the data manually first...with some sample data we could help you with that.

Comment: Please explain your problem more clearly.  As written, your macro is syntactically correct but does not make sense.  Give an example of your two macro variables `&fieldlist` and `&incidentitemlist` and explain what you expect the resulting macro variable `&actualvar` to contain.

Answer (score 1):

I think each time your `do` loop runs it is overwriting the previous value of `actualvar`.  You need to use something like

```
select %scan(&fieldlist,&i) into :actualvar&i ...
```

Then afterwards print out values for `&actualvar1` `&actualvar2` etc... to check your results.

Answer (score 0):

At least you need to put PROC SQL statement inside the DO loop, since your aim is running proc sql for multiple times

```
%do i=1 %to %wordcount(&fieldlist);
    proc sql noprint;
    Select %scan(&fieldlist,&i) into :actualvar separated by ' ' FROM TableA 
    Where IncidentItemId=%scan(&incidentitemlist,&i);
%end;
```

I don't see any problem regarding the rest though. Give it a test and report any error.
I will modify this answer accordingly.

Comment: I don't see why you would need to repeat the `proc sql` block. Having multiple `select` statements inside one block is fine.

Comment: @thelatemail That's true - it would work fine in one block but I like Robbie's suggestion as you will get feedback as it runs if you put the whole block inside the loop.